# Loop over multiple folder in SFTP and dump them in Blob

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a folder, let say A in **SFTP** and this folder has 16 sub-folders, let say A1-P1. Each Sub-folder has 20 **csv** files each.

In my blob storage, I have the same folder with similar name as the **[SFTP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3azCn.jpg)** (A contains A1-P1. I have been able to connect to the **SFTP**, created the connection, created **ForEach** container that contains Copy activities, however I have no idea how these copy activities will connect to individual folder in the blob storage to place the 20
**csv** files in each sub folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction). Because the folder name of your sftp is the same as the folder name of the storage container, you can first use `Get Metadata` to retrieve the sftp folder name, and then use `for each` to copy files.

First create sftp and storage services:

[image]

[image]

In `Get Metadata`, you need to set the dataset:

[image]

Click `open` button, and then config your sftp path:

[image]

Then you can use `copy data` in `for each` to copy files, you need to configure the `Source dataset` and sink dataset.

[image]

Click the `open` button, and then config the `file path`, You need to use `concat` to splice the path in `Get metadata`:

[image]

sink dataset:

[image]